# How to recreate Mac like File Browser in all OS with JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

One thing which varies from OS to OS during UI interaction is the File Browser. The file browser window that pops up when you want to upload a file in Windows is different from the one in Mac. Is it possible with Javascript/CSS/HTML, or may be with a pinch of server side code, to emulate, say, the Mac type file browser, so that a similar kind of window pops up if the user wants to upload file in the Web page from Windows also? (I am not talking about file input, I am asking about the File Browser window where one navigates to find the file he wants to upload..)

Comment: No, it is not possible. And why? The file browser is part of the OS the user is used too, why would you like to display a different one?

Comment: No particular reason. I am new to Mac, and its file browser looks so cool that I have started hating the Windows one already..:) So was wondering that for those who share my hatred, if I can do anything better...

Comment: Part of the reason users stick with a particular operating system is familiarity and general satisfaction with the UI. Think about how you'd feel if some web site found a way to force the Windows file picker on you as you're using your Mac. That's generally how Windows users would feel if you forced the Mac file picker on them. Just don't do it.

Comment: Hmmm, that sounds about right...Won't do. Not that I can, any way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible, and even if it were, it would likely reduce usability. Usability is harmed when host platform conventions are violated. See [the section on inconsistency (second header) in this article](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/okndashcancel-or-cancelndashok/).

Just like the `<input type="file"/>`, the file picker UI is completely up to the browser and host operating system. Neither JavaScript nor the server has direct access to the client's local file system, as this would pose a massive security risk.

Comment: Why is it not possible? Is it entirely OS-specific?

Comment: Yeah, I kind of thought the same too. But when the user selects a file, its name appears in the page, right? So the browser *has* some access to the file system. Can't we tap in there?

Comment: Of course the browser has access to the filesystem. I never said it didn't. How else could it possibly accomplish things like file uploading, let alone storing persistent data across application cycles? But your client JavaScript != the browser, and your JavaScript does not have access to the file system. End of discussion.